# How can I send an iMessage from a different Apple ID than the one the device is registered to?

Tags: ipad, apple-id, messages

We have a family iPad that is registered to my Mom's Apple ID. I'd like to be able to use iMessage, but with *my* Apple ID, not her Apple ID. Is there a way to do this without deregistering the iPad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS devices allow you to use different Apple IDs for different purposes. You can set the Apple ID to be associated with Messages in **Settings > Messages**.

[image: image of settings - messages: click on receive at]

[image: image of settings - messages apple id info]

[image: image of settings - messages apple id sign out]

[image: image of settings - messages apple id sign in]